# IE won't allow users jpg's to upload via PHP - other image extensions work

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

I'm running an image upload script for users where I have allowed png, jpg, jpeg and gif extensions.

When using IE 7-9, users can only successfully submit png's or gif's. IE users can't seem to get a jpg uploading.

I understand about pjpeg and have modified code accordingly due to this IE issue, however, the issue still occurs. Users on IE cannot upload a jpg but other extensions work just fine.

Any hints? Thank you!

**PHP**

```
            $filename = basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);
            $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

            //Edit as per comments below
            $ext = strtolower($ext);

            //Check if the file is a JPG, JPEG, GIF or PNG image and it's size is less than 5Mb
            $allowedExts = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
            if ( (in_array($ext, $allowedExts)) &&
            ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") ||
            ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/png") ||
            //Edit as per comments below
            ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/x-png") ||
            ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/gif") ||
            ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
            && ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] <= 5242880) ){

            //Name it and determine the path to which we want to save this file
            $newname = str_replace( ' ', '_', trim( strip_tags( $_POST['first-name'].'_'.$_POST['last-name'] ) ) ) . '_' . $formKey->generateKey() . '_' . time() . '.jpg';
            ...
```

**FORM**

```
<form id="submit-photo" action="index.php?p=uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['flash_message']) && isset($_SESSION['recent_field']) ) unset($_SESSION['recent_field']); ?>
        <?php $formKey->outputKey(); ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5242880" />
                <div id="upload-photo">
                        <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" />
                </div>
                ...
```

Comment: Have you done an `echo $_FILES["photo"]["type"]` to have a look what value you got when you're using IE?

Comment: `. _ .` is excellent for expressing feelings in documentation but not so much for actual code.

Comment: Good point @oktopus. Will do that now with a `die` after so the page doesn't refresh..

Comment: Besides that I would use [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.pathinfo.php) to determine the filename or extension. It should be more robust with creative filenames than one owns substr-functions.

Comment: Try setting $ext = strtolower($ext); after you do substr... Mayde your extensions are all capital letters like JPG since php is case sensitive it could be potential problem.

Comment: `. _ .` should be `. '_' .` on the `$newname` line.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm going to update code according to each of the advice provided above. Will report back soon.

Comment: `echo $_FILES["photo"]["type"]; die();` produced blank on IE :(

Comment: Solved by commenting out `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5242880" />` as I do a file size check in php :) Don't know why IE didn't like it! Thanks everyone for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar issues with IE (especially 7 and 8), usually it was due to the "image/x-png" MIME type that IE fires when uploading a png image.
Try adding that to your MIME list

```
$_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/x-png"
```

Consider thought that the MIME type can be spoofed, and it's not a fully reliable assessment of an image. You should use something like [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to check for a real image, and  `pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` (see [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)) to get an extension from a file;

Comment: @oktopus Damn, I mean xpng not pjpeg, I messed it up. Anyway, the reasoning for evaluating an image still stands

Comment: Thanks Damien, I'll give it a crack now. Although png uploads fine on IE (as far as I'm aware, 7-9), is there a different fix for jpg's?